# MVVM Light how to determinte which records changed

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, mvvm, mvvm-light

in MVVM Light, if I have a datagrid binded(2 way) to an obersvable collection, and when I finally hit update after editing couple records and adding new ones, how do I determine which ones have been added new and which ones have been edited. (I guess which have primary key id = 0 can still be flagged as new but how to check which were edited)

Is there an inbuilt property? or I have create a property to flag those records?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to the `CollectionChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` to find that out.

```
private void MyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    { 
         //use e.NewItems for added items
    }
    else if(e.Action == otifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
         //use e.OldItems for removed items
    }
    ...
 }
```

As for finding out which ones have been edited this does not act on the collection itself but on the entities within the collection. A good idea is to have a `ViewModel`/`Model` represent each row and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or have `IsDirty` property that you can check against.

So when an item gets added attach to some event that will alert you of any changes. (you can do this inside the above `CollectionChanged` handler or some method that creates the model for you).

```
model.PropertyChanged += ModelChanged;
...
private void ModelChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Model model = (Model)sender;
    //Record in your own way that model has changed.
}
```